# Error al cambiar de ruta en Next.js

Tags: next.js, enlace

Estoy teniendo un problema y no se por donde puede venir, asi que voy a tratar de explicarlo y de dejar parte del codigo, pero seguramente voy a tener que ir añadiendo partes mas adelante.

Tengo una app en Next 12, y tiene un menu para navegar por el sitio.

En la app existen paginas dinamicas, y una de ellas es `/pages/[ciudad]/[...filtros].js` que es donde ocurre el problema.

El problema basicamente es asi:

- Si yo estoy parado en el home de mi sitio, y hago click en cualquier link de mi menu, por ejemplo, `/favoritos`, la url cambia, el menu se cierra, me dirige a la pagina de favoritos y el contenido se carga correctamente.
- Si yo ahora abro el menu y me dirijo a algun link que matchee con `/pages/[ciudad]/[...filtros].js`, todo funciona correctamente como en el punto anterior (En el caso de este tipo de paginas, muestran informacion de un CMS y de una base de datos)
- Si yo ahora (estando en una pagina del tipo `/pages/[ciudad]/[...filtros].js`) abro el menu y me dirijo a otra pagina del tipo `/pages/[ciudad]/[...filtros].js`, es cuando aparece el problema:

**La url del navegador cambia correctamente, pero ni se cierra el menu, ni se reemplazan los datos de la base de datos. Pero sí se reemplazan los datos del CMS.**

> Si yo actualizo la pagina o si llego a ellas escribiendo la direccion a mano, todo anda bien. El problema es cuando cambio entre paginas `[...filtros].js` utilizando el menu de mi app.

No entiendo por donde viene el problema, asi que dejo el codigo de `/pages/[ciudad]/[...filtros].js`

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    fallback: "blocking",
    paths: [],
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ctx => {

  const filterDetails = ...

  return {
    props: {
      pageData: {
        ...
        filterDetails,
      },
      ...
    },
    revalidate: parseInt(process.env.FILTERED_SEARCH_RESULTS_REGEN_TIME || "240", 10),
  };
};

export default Search;
```

Como el error me ocurre solamente al usar el menu, dejo el codigo de cada boton del menu, capaz me falta alguna propiedad por aca:

```
   <Link
      href={href}
    >
      <a
        alt={alt || `${text} button`}
        className={`menu-item-wrapper${_removeBorder ? " no-border" : ""}${_selected ? " selected" : ""}`}
        target={newTab}
      >
        {_children}
      </a>
    </Link>
```

Pero tambien hay cosas mas complejas, como un hook `useSearch` que se encarga de filtrar los resultados (ya que en [...filtros].js, al igual que en otras paginas del sitio, se muestran resultados de busqueda). No se si el problema tendra que ver con esa parte, y es mucho mas grande, por eso por el momento solo comparto esto, capaz hay un error por aca. Muchas gracias.